# Endpoint info in the request-handler-advice-chain

Tags: spring-integration

My requirement is to calculate the total time consumed by external sources like jdbc, web service etc.,

I have added request-handler-advice-chain in the required endpoints and calculated the time. It works perfectly.
I have to add the identifier of the endpoint component as well. Is there any way to get the endpoint id via advice class.

Ex:

```
    <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway id="myProcID" request-channel="myChannel" data-source="dataSource"
....
        <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
             <ref bean="statsAdvice" />
        </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain> 
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Can I get the jdbc endpoint id in advice class? Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Advice class extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice  and when I try to cast
    NamedComponent component = (NamedComponent)target;

I am getting the below exception - `org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway#0]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler`

Fix is working fine with 4.3.2 release:

```
((AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.RequestHandler) target).getAdvisedHandler().getComponentName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your advice extends `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` the target object is available as a parameter in `doInvoke` - see [the javadocs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/handler/advice/AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java#L127).

Cast it to `NamedComponent` and call `getComponentName()`.

If you implemented `MethodInterceptor` directly, use `invocation.getThis()` to get a reference to the handler.

Comment: Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, yes; sorry; I forgot about that wrapper - we should provide access to its delegate; please open an improvement [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: Please find the jira request: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4085?jql=project%20%3D%20%22INT%22%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Minor%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC

Comment: It is working fine with 4.3.2 release. I have updated the syntax in the question for other's reference.